# How Can I Delete Index and Trigger when Exporting MySql?

Tags: python, mysql

Hello to everyone,

With mysqldump, I export the schema and data of the database.

Here's my code:

```
self.BACKUP_PATH = 'SqlBackup'
self.FILE_NAME_SCHEMA = self.BACKUP_PATH + '/tribot_schema_pack.sql'
self.FILE_NAME_DATA_PACK = self.BACKUP_PATH + '/tribot_data_pack.sql'

self.MYSQL_SETTINGS = '-h ' + self.DB_HOST + ' -u ' + self.DB_USER + ' --password=' + self.DB_USER_PASSWORD
self.DUMP_CODE = self.MYSQL_DUMP_DIR + '/mysqldump ' + self.MYSQL_SETTINGS
self.DUMP_MYSQL_CODE = self.MYSQL_DUMP_DIR + '/mysql ' + self.MYSQL_SETTINGS

command_schema = '%s --no-data --skip-triggers %s > %s' % \
                 (self.DUMP_CODE, self.DB_NAME, pipes.quote(self.FILE_NAME_SCHEMA))

command_data = '%s --no-create-info %s > %s' % \
               (self.DUMP_CODE, self.DB_NAME, pipes.quote(self.FILE_NAME_DATA_PACK))

subprocess.Popen(command_schema, shell=True).wait()

subprocess.Popen(command_data, shell=True).wait()
```

How do I do not want to import index and triggers while exporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
command_schema = '%s --no-data --skip-triggers --disable-keys %s > %s' % \
                 (self.DUMP_CODE, self.DB_NAME, pipes.quote(self.FILE_NAME_SCHEMA))

command_data = '%s --no-create-info --skip-triggers --disable-keys %s > %s' % \
               "`ALTER TABLE tribot_place_raw_placetags DROP FOREIGN KEY tribot_place_raw_placetags_citynames;`"
    "`ALTER TABLE ``tribot_place_raw_placetags`` DROP INDEX ``tribot_place_raw_placetags_citynames``;`"
```

I didn't get the triggers like this: **--skip-triggers**

For the keys I, unfortunately, remove the keys I have appeared on the sample;

```
"`ALTER TABLE tribot_place_raw_placetags DROP FOREIGN KEY tribot_place_raw_placetags_citynames;`"

"`ALTER TABLE ``tribot_place_raw_placetags`` DROP INDEX ``tribot_place_raw_placetags_citynames``;`"
```